# Monthly breakdown of numbers

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I'm extracting data from the database where all the dates fields exit based on the Fiscal Year (starting from October) and Fiscal Month. I have 2 date fields based on the received date and closed date and extracting separate received date FY and closed date fiscal year.
I have calculated years numbers based on the condition which works fine. Now, I want to break it down by the month where I'm experiencing wired issue such as its missing current year one month (October) data for few records else it works fine. I checked everything in terms of data wise, everything looks good.
I want to know if I'm using the right formula for this? Attaching a data model for your reference.

[image]

this is the formula I'm implementing.

```
CALCULATE(COUNT(table[id]), 
                          FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(table,  table[office], table[Fiscal_month_Closed]), 
                         (table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] = SELECTEDVALUE(table[Fiscal_Year])))
```

Above formula works fine for the year selection. It doesn't provide correct values while adding closed month (table[Fiscal_month_Closed]) in here.

I want to counts ids by office where closed year is equal to selected value of the fiscal year and break it down by month_closed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
CALCULATE(
  COUNT(table[id]),
  ALLEXCEPT(table, table[office], table[Fiscal_month_Closed]), 
  table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] = table[Fiscal_Year]
)
```

Comment: Thank you, Sam, for helping! I tried your suggested answers above, however, none of these works as expected, and this condition is must to implement 
(table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] = SELECTEDVALUE(table[Fiscal_Year]). How can I break it down by month_closed by implementing this condition?
```
CALCULATE(COUNT(table[id]), 
                          FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(table,  table[office], table[Fiscal_month_Closed]), 
                         (table[Fiscal_Year_Closed] = SELECTEDVALUE(table[Fiscal_Year]))) ``` and Dropdown is based on the fiscal year received not the fiscal year closed

Comment: Updated answer above.

Comment: I'm using the same formula currently. But I'm experiencing missing numbers for month of October as I have highlighted above

Comment: If it is working for every month apart from one then you need to double check the data, especially any calculations involving dates where a `<` vs `<=` makes a difference. Or subtracting dates, sometimes you need to add `+ 1` etc...

Comment: Clearly you have sensitive data but if you could share a mock pbix with dummy data that illustrates the problem, then we can help further.

Comment: Thank you Sam for helping! I'll take a look at the backend.